# Word "Purchase" in SAAS Subscription Model

Tags: word-choice

In a subscription model, the user is not purchasing the application, they just subscribe and pay based on the billing cycle. So, I've a doubt whether can we use the word 'Purchase'.

Comment: What are you asking about?  Whether it's OK to use the word "purchase" for a subscription?

Comment: @deadrat Yes. Let's take an example, Can I say Purchase History of your subscriptions?

Comment: @Eilia. Thanks for your reply. I just want to know, whether it's OK to use the word 'purchase' in the subscription model. Since the customer is not getting the subscribed product for permanent. They subscribe (monthly, quarterly or yearly) to the product and pay till they need it. Once they cancel the subscription, they didn't own any.

Comment: @Eilia A comment good enough that I think you should promote it to an answer.

Comment: @deadrat, Agreed!

Comment: @RajendraPrasad I think Eilia has the answer with regard to usage.  You'll have to decide whether using the phrase will encourage people to think they're purchased the software rather than a subscription for its use.  But that's a business consideration.

Comment: How about "Subscription Purchase History"

Comment: @Jim. Yes. We can phrase the sentence based on the word "Purchase" as you said. But my question is whether I can use the word"Purchase" or not.
Thanks for your comment

Comment: Yes you can.  Here a relevant ngram with some baseline phrases included to give you some idea about frequency of use. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purchase+a+subscription%2Cbuy+a+subscription%2Cbuy+a+snake%2Cbuy+a+dog&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurchase%20a%20subscription%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuy%20a%20subscription%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuy%20a%20snake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuy%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation described in the OP is called [Pay-Per-Use Software (SaaS)](http://apprenda.com/library/glossary/definition-payperuse-software-saas/).

And using *purchase* is common in the field. Take the following sentence as an example:

> **Pay Per Use software licensing agreements** for HDC Series system cameras offer users greater flexibility and significant cost savings. The software licensing agreements enable Sony customers to **purchase temporary licenses** for shooting at....